# Visualizar una sola grafica con highcharts

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts

Sigo aprendiendo a usar detalles de higcharts y ahora lo que quiero hacer es que con el siguiente puedo visualizar 3 lineas al mismo tiempo y pues activarlas o desactivarlas cuando yo quiera

```
DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("StockChart")
                        // DotNet.Highstock.Highstock chart = new DotNet.Highstock.Highstock("Chart")
                        .InitChart(new Chart
                        {
                            Type = ChartTypes.Line,
                            ZoomType = ZoomTypes.X,
                            Width = 900,
                            Height = 300
                            //DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line,
                            //ZoomType = ZoomTypes.X,
                            //SpacingRight = 20
                        })
                        .SetTitle(new Title
                        {
                            Text = ""
                        })
                        .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
                        {
                            Line = new PlotOptionsLine
                            {
                                EnableMouseTracking = false,
                                Animation = new Animation(true) { },

                            },
                        })
                        .SetXAxis(new XAxis
                        {
                            Labels = new XAxisLabels
                            {
                                Enabled = false
                            }
                        })
                        .SetYAxis(new YAxis
                        {
                            Title = new YAxisTitle
                            {
                                Text = ""
                            },
                            Labels = new YAxisLabels
                            {
                                Enabled = false
                            }

                        })
                        .SetSeries(new[]
                        {
                        new Series
                        {
                            Name = "ECG1",
                            Data = new Data(chartValues)   // Here we put the dbase data into the chart               
                        },                   
                        new Series
                        {
                            Name = "ECG2",
                            Data = new Data(chartValues2)
                        },
                        new Series
                        {
                            Name = "ECG3",
                            Data = new Data(chartValues3)
                        }
                    });

            chrtMyChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
```

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es que al activar una grafica las otras dos se desactiven y solo visualizar una a la vez